# Google Java Format unable to read file while formatting

Tags: java, ant, google-java-format

I've added an ant task to format sources before compilation.
However, the formatter comes up a cropper when provided a list of file paths and skips (is unable to read) a file when run as a java Ant task.
Running the same as a script individually or as a batch does not produce the same error.

Is this a problem with the java Ant task?
Setting fork = "True" in the java task has no effect. The result code returned is still 1.

The bash scripts are available at my repository [LearnJava](https://github.com/Fernal73/LearnJava).

The scripts  are: buildant, buildantall, format and formatall.

Build.xml and build.properties are under each project directory.

The projects you can try to run the scripts against individually are Facade2 and Composite2.

You will need at least JDK 8 to compile all. JDK 7 will do for all other projects except Composite2 that uses lambda expressions.

Thanks in advance.

The ant task is set up as follows:

```
<target name="gformat">
    <exec executable="find" dir="${basedir}"
        failonerror="true" outputproperty="sources">
        <arg line=" . -type f -name '*.java'"/>
    </exec>

    <echo message="About to format ...: ${sources}"/>

    <java classname="${gformat.main.class}">
        <arg line=" -i ${sources}"/>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="../${gformat.jar}"/>
            <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

---

I was able to fix the above error by substituting the exec task with the following:

```
<fileset dir="${basedir}" id="javasrcs">
      <include name="**/*.java" />
    </fileset>
    <pathconvert property="sources" refid="javasrcs" pathsep=" " />
```

NOW, how do I close this query?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the find task is that it puts a line separator between each file name as against a space character that the formatter expects on the command line. The solution is to either grep and replace the line separator with space or use the ant task as above with a space separator specified.